# pyinstaller saying 'failed to execute script gui'

Tags: python, api, user-interface, tkinter

i made a gui with tkinter which gets the weather data from open weather api and displays on screen.
Now i want to make this an .exe. So i used pyinstaller to do that, it builds to .exe without showing any problem but the problem is it gives error when i try to execute the .exe in the `dist` directory.

I used to following command to build it - `pyinstaller --onefile gui.py`

i even tried the following code - `pyinstaller --onefile -w gui.py`
still no luck.

edit :
I also ran `pyinstaller --onefile -c gui.py', a terminal window opens and then dumps a bunch of text and then closes.
the dump :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wforcast as forcast
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\kakshipth\documents\coding\py\virtualauto\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "wforcast.py", line 48, in <module>
    save_way('Hyderabad')
  File "wforcast.py", line 33, in save_way
    with open(path_to_json, 'w') as data :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'practice\\coolshitzz\\weather\\data.json'
[1488] Failed to execute script gui
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Did you copy the exe to the project directory?

Comment: i think, i dont need to copy it where my source files are. But i still did, and im getting the same error

Comment: Yes you need to take it to where the source files are, or else, the path said in the code is wrong and hence it wont execute, anyway try this code `pyinstaller --onefile -c gui.py` and copy to the project directory and let me know the error that comes up in the console.

Comment: hey, it works. The problem was in the module i imported, i executed one of the functions bymistake and the path in that def was relative, so my program was unable to find it. So, once i removed the def call. It works perfectly now. But there is this ugly terminal window which tags along, is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here is that, the relative paths to the source files become invalid and hence the error, so two ways to solve this.

**First way:**
Make an exe with `pyinstaller -F -w gui.py` and copy the exe to the project directory or the location where all relative paths will be identified.

**Second Way:**
Remove the call to the relative path and make an exe with `pyinstaller -F -w gui.py` and now since it does not have dependencies or relative paths, it should work fine on your system.

The above two codes serve same purpose as your previous code, just that i made it shorter, to type faster.

The console was just there to identify the error that came up, you can get rid of console by replacing `-c` with `-w` or just use the same code as you used previously, following the above methods.

Hope it solved the problem, if any errors or doubts, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: thanks, i found the problem and fixed it. But thanks any way